# What is loaded when Android application starts

Tags: android, memory-management

I was wondering about what is loaded into memory when an application is started up.

Does the whole of the APK get loaded or only parts?
This is important for me when conidering the size of my APK (which can be very big is there is a lot of graphics).

The important thing to add here is that it is not my application. It was commissioned from a fourth-party by someone I know who knows zero about computing - never mind Android.
He wanted to know if those numbers made sense or should he be asking questions about it since it makes it difficult for the application to run on some devices.
I even had some problems on my Galaxy 3.

More information:

We are talking about a game where the APK size is about 100MB.
When the application starts up it immediately uses about 80MB of memory and soon shoots up to over 100MB. And this is just when the splash screen and menu come up.

The application is outsourced by a third party that I am connected to. I can't say more than that for fear using this as an ad.

This is the meminfo I get via adb:

```
                         Shared  Private     Heap     Heap     Heap
               Pss    Dirty    Dirty     Size    Alloc     Free
            ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
   Native        0        0        0    67048    65871      112
   Dalvik    10235    13272     9676    16468    15267     1201
    Stack       28        8       28
   Cursor        0        0        0
   Ashmem        6       12        0
Other dev       68       36        0
 .so mmap    13959     3200     2120
.jar mmap        0        0        0
.apk mmap       98        0        0
.ttf mmap       22        0        0
.dex mmap     2639      520       36


 Other mmap      152        8        8
      Unknown    72564      336    72560
        TOTAL    99771    17392    84428    83516    81138     1313

 Objects
               Views:       17         ViewRootImpl:        1
         AppContexts:        3           Activities:        1
              Assets:        3        AssetManagers:        3
       Local Binders:       18        Proxy Binders:       26
    Death Recipients:        1
     OpenSSL Sockets:        1

 SQL
         MEMORY_USED:      368
  PAGECACHE_OVERFLOW:       78          MALLOC_SIZE:       62
```

Comment: It will depend on what you specified to load.

Comment: What Howlin said. What gets loaded to your application is exactly what you specified to be loaded. Some resources get loaded / unloaded manually or via garbage collection, but I guess there is no real measurement or standard to what gets loaded, it all comes down to the kind of application you designed.

Comment: @Howlin I have added some more notes to the question

Answer (score 0):

You needn't think in terms of Application or especially in terms of the apk file. What gets loaded depends on what your launcher activity, which you have declared in your manifest file, is. You should be just checking what gets loaded while bringing the launcher activity to life. An application is a collection of activities, rather than a unified entity on its own.

Comment: I have added more details of the source of the application and exact memory usage.